# Check queries output type

Tags: oracle, types

I'm working with Oracle DB and faced with a problem. I cannot say for sure what the type will value have once the output is generated.
I have the following simple query:

```
select 1+'1234' from dual;
```

For me it's clear that the output "**1235**" will present a simple number. But how can I check that it is not converted into text afterwards for example? Is there any kind of *"type_of"* function which will help me with that?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the `dump()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/DUMP.html):

```
select dump(1+'1234') from dual;
```

which will give you the [datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6), as well as the byte values used to represent tha value, which you don’t seem to be interested in here.

```
Typ=2 Len=3: 194,13,36
```

where type 2 is NUMBER.

Answer (score 1):

I think a way to find the return type would be to create a table using that query.

for eg.

```
create table temp_table_name1 as select 1+'1234' a from dual;

desc temp_table_name1;
```

Should give the type.

If you are worried about the return type then you can manually set it using

```
select Cast(1+'1234' As Varchar2(30)) a from dual;
```

OR

```
select Cast(1+'1234' As Number(4)) a from dual;
```

Comment: yeah I know this workaround, but unfortunately I try to consider such a option that someone doesn't have privileges to create temp tables, just to find the type of the output and then drop it :(